# Odd Permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Prove that the product of two odd permutations is even.

---

I'm having a difficult time doing this in the general case. I have that if s is even, then $$\alpha = (a_1a_2a_3...a_{s-1}a_s)=(a_1a_s)(a_1a_{s-1})...(a_1a_3)(a_1a_2)$$ and $$\alpha^2=(a_1a_3a_5...a_sa_2a_4...a_{s-1})=(a_1a_{s-1})...(a_1a_4)(a_1a_2)(a_1a_s)...(a_1a_3).$$ But how do I even show that that is even?

Im totally lost

Comment: The product of two odd permutations is even, not odd.

Comment: @allie What definitions of "odd permutation" and "even permutation" are you using?

Comment: Whoops you're right Sanath. And Nicholas - a permutation is odd if it is a product of an odd number of transpositions. Similarly a permutation is even if it is a product of an even number of transpositions.

Comment: If the definition is that simple, isn't it just a matter of adding together the number of transpositions?  Say $x=yz$ where $y$ and $z$ can be written as the product of $m$ and $n$ transpositions respectively, where $m$ and $n$ are odd numbers.  Then immediately $x$ can be written as a product of $m+n$ transpositions, and $m+n$ is even because it is a sum of two odd numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If $x,y\in S_n$ are both odd permutations the they are both the product of an odd number of transpositions, say $m,n$ respectively

Then $xy$ is the product of $m+n$ transposition which is even hence result.